# What is the name of this choy?

Tags: vegetables

I'm trying to make pickles with the following vegetables:
[image]

However, I don't know what it is called and where to get it.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi. While the picture that you posted is a vegetable, which has the same root as vegetarianism, this is not a Q&A for identifying vegetables and as such, your question does not belong here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Veganism & Vegetarianism Stack Exchange site.As your question is not really related to vegetarianism, it is considered off-topic here.

Comment: I think you meant to ask this of the Cooking Stack Exchange site... they have a food identification tag that this would probably fall under (https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-identification)

That having been said, according to this, it's Gai Choy: http://greenandfreshtx.com/unique-asian-vegetables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though it might be [yu choy sum](https://images.app.goo.gl/776UshsAj5ft6EfH6)